# Switch over tab previous data is coming

Tags: java, android

I have added a tab bar in my application with four tabs like home stock etc .In that tab bar I have used a nested activity using activity group for all tabs. By default, the home page will show up to the user. If I switch stock tab I am calling stock activity group class from stock activity class. In stock activity I have edittext view with list view. If the users enters 'a' or 'A' value into textwatcher listener I list the value in listview. If I click home tab and come back to the stock tab, that value in listview shows up again. Can anybody tell me how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using ontabchangelistener